# json variable with ajax and php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

I have a table that queries from a database that is updated frequently, and where `<span id="totalvotes1"></span>` and where `<span id="totalvotes2"></span>` I need to be able to be able to identify those in the line `success: function(data) { $('#totalvotes1').text(data); } });` in my ajax for each corresponding row queried... the way it is set up right now, my ajax will just display the information back into `<span id="totalvotes1"></span>` in the last row queried.... apparently I need to use json to accomplish this but I have no idea how... any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
<?php

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blogData ORDER BY id DESC");
$sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE mod(mes_id,2) = 0 ORDER BY mes_id DESC");
$sql3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE mod(mes_id,2) = 1 ORDER BY mes_id DESC");

$count_variable = 0;

while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))AND($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))AND($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) ){
$id = $row['id'];
$title = $row['title'];
$content = $row['content'];
$category = $row['category'];
$podcast = $row['podcast'];
$datetime = $row['datetime'];

$message1=$row2['msg'];
$mes_id1=$row2['mes_id'];
$totalvotes1=$row2['totalvotes'];

$message2=$row3['msg'];
$mes_id2=$row3['mes_id'];
$totalvotes2=$row3['totalvotes'];


?>

<table class="content">
<tr>
<td>


<div id="main">
<div id="left">
<span class='up'><a href="" class="vote" name="up" data-options="key1=<?php echo $mes_id1;?>&key2=<?php echo $mes_id2;?>"><img src="up.png" alt="Down" /></a></span><br />
<span id="totalvotes1"><?php echo $totalvotes1; ?></span><br />
</div>
<div id="message">
<?php echo $message1; ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div id="main">
<div id="right">
<br />
<span id="totalvotes2"><?php echo $totalvotes2; ?></span><br />
<span class='down'><a href="" class="vote" name="down" data-options="key1=<?php echo  $mes_id1;?>&key2=<?php echo $mes_id2;?>"><img src="down.png" alt="Down" /></a></span>
</div>
<div id="message">
<?php echo $message2; ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
 }
?>
```

here is my general.js file

```
$(".vote").click(function()  
{

var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var eData = $(this).attr("data-options");
var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&' + eData ;
var parent = $(this);


if(name=='up')
{

$(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "up.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,

success: function(data) { $('#totalvotes1').text(data); }
});

}
else
{

$(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "down.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,

success: function(data) { $('#totalvotes2').text(data); }

});


}
});


});
});
```

Comment: You don't show it here, but do you still have the `id` attribute on your links?  If so, and you number those like the `totalvotes`, you can use that in your JS selector like ` $('#totalvotes'+id).text(data);` ^^

Comment: could I use $('#totalvotes'+ mes_id1).text(data); ?  $mes_id1 is sent on my links. im not quite sure what you're saying there...

Comment: would I be able to get your email or facebook Jon...? just to make it easier to chat...

Comment: i get what you're saying and no I don't have the id attribute on my links, my links are the same as they are displayed above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you have multiple spans on your page with the same ids: `totalvotes1` and `totalvotes2`. So when you do `$('#totalvotes1').text(data);` the browser has no idea which one to change.

To counter this, you may consider the following approach. First, change ids of the spans by adding unique key of the product.

```
<span id="total_vote_up_<?php echo $id; ?>">
<span id="total_vote_down_<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

Second thing to change is the id of the link that fires the event. You can make it's id similar to the one spans have to make it easy to change spans' content without JSON.

```
<a class="vote" name="up" id="vote_up_<?php echo $id; ?>"...>
<a class="vote" name="down" id="vote_down_<?php echo $id; ?>"...>
```

As you can see, ids are similar. This allows you to do the following to change the spans content:

```
success: function(data) { $('#total_' + $(this).attr("id")). text(data); }
```

Basically, it will take the id of the link (say, `vote_up_123`) and put total votes amount into the span with id of `total_vote_up_123`.

Comment: i totally see how this is supposed to work and that's perfect but I can't get it to function right... let me get back to you on that...

Comment: its definitely just not working for me.... I can't figure out why... is there anything missing in what you posted...?

Comment: i basically just used your same code but instead of <?php echo $id; ?> I used <?php echo $mes_id; ?> cuz that's the unique id im working with. but this doesn't function right, the ajax just displays blank space now

Comment: Well you need to debug it... "doesn't work" is not very helpful. Put the code on web and provide a link or use firebug to see which errors are happening.